# How to prove unfold-reverse for Vec?

Tags: agda

The Agda standard library has a few properties on how `reverse` and `_++_` work on `List`. Trying to transfer these proofs to `Vec` appears to be non-trivial (disregarding universes):

```
open import Data.Nat
open import Data.Vec
open import Relation.Binary.HeterogeneousEquality

unfold-reverse : {A : Set} → (x : A) → {n : ℕ} → (xs : Vec A n) →
                 reverse (x ∷ xs) ≅ reverse xs ++ [ x ]
```

TL;DR: How to prove `unfold-reverse`?

The rest of this question outlines approaches to doing so and explains what problems surface.

The type of this property is very similar to the `List` counter part in `Data.List.Properties`. The proof involves a helper which roughly translates to:

```
open import Function

helper : ∀ {n m} → (xs : Vec A n) → (ys : Vec A m) →
         foldl (Vec A ∘ (flip _+_ n)) (flip _∷_) xs ys ≅ reverse ys ++ xs
```

Trying to insert this helper in `unfold-reverse` fails, because the left hand `reverse` is a `foldl` application with `Vec A ∘ suc` as first argument whereas the left hand side of `helper` has a `foldl` application with `Vec A ∘ (flip _+_ 1)` as first argument. Even though `suc ≗ flip _+_ 1` is readily available from `Data.Nat.Properties.Simple`, it cannot be used here as `cong` would need a non-pointwise equality here and we don't have extensionality without further assumptions.

Removing the `flip` from `flip _+_ n` in `helper` yields a type error, so that is no option either.

Any other ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Data.Vec.Properties` module contains this function:

```
foldl-cong : ∀ {a b} {A : Set a}
               {B₁ : ℕ → Set b}
               {f₁ : ∀ {n} → B₁ n → A → B₁ (suc n)} {e₁}
               {B₂ : ℕ → Set b}
               {f₂ : ∀ {n} → B₂ n → A → B₂ (suc n)} {e₂} →
             (∀ {n x} {y₁ : B₁ n} {y₂ : B₂ n} →
                y₁ ≅ y₂ → f₁ y₁ x ≅ f₂ y₂ x) →
             e₁ ≅ e₂ →
             ∀ {n} (xs : Vec A n) →
             foldl B₁ f₁ e₁ xs ≅ foldl B₂ f₂ e₂ xs
foldl-cong           _     e₁=e₂ []       = e₁=e₂
foldl-cong {B₁ = B₁} f₁=f₂ e₁=e₂ (x ∷ xs) =
  foldl-cong {B₁ = B₁ ∘ suc} f₁=f₂ (f₁=f₂ e₁=e₂) xs
```

Here is more or less elaborated solution:

```
unfold-reverse : {A : Set} → (x : A) → {n : ℕ} → (xs : Vec A n) →
                 reverse (x ∷ xs) ≅ reverse xs ++ (x ∷ [])
unfold-reverse x xs = begin
  foldl (Vec _ ∘ _+_ 1) (flip _∷_) (x ∷ []) xs
    ≅⟨ (foldl-cong
         {B₁ = Vec _ ∘ _+_ 1}
         {f₁ = flip _∷_}
         {e₁ = x ∷ []}
         {B₂ = Vec _ ∘ flip _+_ 1}
         {f₂ = flip _∷_}
         {e₂ = x ∷ []}
         (λ {n} {a} {as₁} {as₂} as₁≅as₂ -> {!!})
         refl
         xs) ⟩
  foldl (Vec _ ∘ flip _+_ 1) (flip _∷_) (x ∷ []) xs
    ≅⟨ helper (x ∷ []) xs  ⟩
  reverse xs ++ x ∷ []
  ∎
```

Note, that only `B₁` and `B₂` are distinct in the arguments of the `foldl-cong` function. After simplifying context in the hole we have

```
Goal: a ∷ as₁ ≅ a ∷ as₂
————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————
as₁≅as₂ : as₁ ≅ as₂
as₂     : Vec A (n + 1)
as₁     : Vec A (1 + n)
a       : A
n       : ℕ
A       : Set
```

So we need to prove, that at each recursive call adding an element to an accumulator of type `Vec A (n + 1)` is equal to adding an element to an accumulator of type `Vec A (1 + n)`, and then results of two `foldl`s are equal. The proof itself is simple. Here is the whole code:

```
open import Function
open import Relation.Binary.HeterogeneousEquality
open import Data.Nat
open import Data.Vec
open import Data.Nat.Properties.Simple
open import Data.Vec.Properties

open ≅-Reasoning

postulate
  helper : ∀ {n m} {A : Set} (xs : Vec A n) (ys : Vec A m)
         -> foldl (Vec A ∘ flip _+_ n) (flip _∷_) xs ys ≅ reverse ys ++ xs

cong' : ∀ {α β γ} {I : Set α} {i j : I}
      -> (A : I -> Set β) {B : {k : I} -> A k -> Set γ} {x : A i} {y : A j}
      -> i ≅ j
      -> (f : {k : I} -> (x : A k) -> B x)
      -> x ≅ y
      -> f x ≅ f y
cong' _ refl _ refl = refl

unfold-reverse : {A : Set} → (x : A) → {n : ℕ} → (xs : Vec A n) →
                 reverse (x ∷ xs) ≅ reverse xs ++ (x ∷ [])
unfold-reverse x xs = begin
  foldl (Vec _ ∘ _+_ 1) (flip _∷_) (x ∷ []) xs
    ≅⟨ (foldl-cong
         {B₁ = Vec _ ∘ _+_ 1}
         {f₁ = flip _∷_}
         {e₁ = x ∷ []}
         {B₂ = Vec _ ∘ flip _+_ 1}
         {f₂ = flip _∷_}
         {e₂ = x ∷ []}
         (λ {n} {a} {as₁} {as₂} as₁≅as₂ -> begin
            a ∷ as₁
              ≅⟨ cong' (Vec _) (sym (≡-to-≅ (+-comm n 1))) (_∷_ a) as₁≅as₂ ⟩
            a ∷ as₂
            ∎)
         refl
         xs) ⟩
  foldl (Vec _ ∘ flip _+_ 1) (flip _∷_) (x ∷ []) xs
    ≅⟨ helper (x ∷ []) xs  ⟩
  reverse xs ++ x ∷ []
  ∎
```

Comment: The pointer to `foldl-cong` and how it is to be used is the important bit here. It is also needed to prove `helper`. With the associativity of `_++_` and some more standard library results, `helper` can also be proven. Some variant of the indexed cong for heterogeneous equality clearly belongs to the standard library.